# Re-order posts inside tax query

Tags: post-meta, order, pre-get-posts

I have some posts having some custom fields and their value. I have custom fields like `featured` and `expiry_date`, whose values are `yes/no` and `some date` respectively.

All these posts are coming under custom taxonomy called `stores`.

My requirement is to list posts like, featured posts first and then other posts and order by `expiry_date` , `ASC`.

Below is my code but it's not working properly.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'orange_alter_posts' );

function orange_alter_posts( $query ) {

    if(is_tax('store')) {
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
                                            array(
                                                'key'       => 'featured',
                                                'value'     => 'yes',
                                            )
                                        )
                    );
    }
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'alter_posts_orderby');
function alter_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby_statement = "('listing_expiry_date')";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Sorry for the question title, it's may not matching to the description.

Could anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: In which format `expiry_date` stored?

Comment: @sakibmoon The Date format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`.